# What is the maximum number of active connections a client can have to a server IP? (networking)

Tags: networking, network-programming

I came to my knowledge that if a machine makes 2 requests to the same destination IP and the same destination port, the source ports have to be different. But if that is the case, there must be a maximum number of active connections a client can have to a server. Is there a limit on how many such connections there can be?

Comment: At the network and transport layers, there are no clients or servers. Client/server is an application concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A port is 16 bits, so the absolute limit would be 2<sup>16</sup>.

Of course, port 0 is not really ever used and ports 1 to 1023 are clearly reserved for servers. Plus, in most cases, you have a *limited* range of ports you can use to connect as a client. These are called ephemeral ports and are between 49152 and 65535.

The number 49152 is 0xC000. So you get the top quarter of the ports available to clients or 16384 ports (2<sup>14</sup>). That's your limit as a client.

Note that memory is also required. More or less depending on your application but also the kernel needs enough memory to allocate so many ports. So you are more likely to run out of memory before you can allocate that many ports (unless, like me, you have a computer with 512Mb of RAM or more... then you'll have a hard time to stress the memory allocation in most cases).

In practical use, I've never run out of client ports. The main issue I run into is multiple applications trying to listen on the same port (i.e. two servers trying to listen on port 80, for example).

Comment: Thanks Alexis. you are so awesome.